# Unable to link App to Google games services, SHA1 already linked to packagename

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-play-games

1. Sign in Google Play Console.
2. Select Games services
3. Select Add new game.
4. Fill in required details.
5. Select link app, -> Android.
6. Select the package name I would like to link to.
7. Add SHA1 fingerprint.
8. Error. Sorry and application with this SHA1 fingerprint is already linked to this app.

I have unpublished the only game service in my console, logged into Google API console and scheduled it for deletion.
I have attempted this 10 times over the space of a week? Hoping that something needed to be deregistered / or unlinked on google servers and my next attempt would work.

I have tried this in a different Google Play Console Account and it worked without issues.

I would really like to link game services such as leaderboards and saved games to my app.

***We also have a Firebase account linked to this app, with the same packagename and SHA1 fingerprint.***
Please tell me I don't need to delete the Firebase account as well, to link a new Game service to this App.

Comment: Hi @Jasper I think will be hard to help you with this issue. I recommend you to write google helpwith this problem. Usually they respond in a couple of days. Good Luck!

Comment: Hello, this troubleshooting video from Google helped me for a similar issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkJS_W-VC9I . explanations for SHA1 and package start at 18 min 40s. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Lolo06 for the suggestion. That video definitely helped me get a better understanding how the SHA1 and package names are linked for API calls. However I am still not sure why I can't create a new game service linked to my app? I've un-published and deleted all game services in my Google play console. I have a feeling Firebase has something to do with this? but I can't delete that unless I know 100% that's the issue, as other people in my company are reliant on it, and deleting it would disrupt their work.

Comment: When creating your Games through the Google Play console, you must understand there is also the Google API console behind the scene: https://console.developers.google.com/ . As explained in the troubleshooting video, in normal case you should not create items directly/manually in this Google API console. Games is doing it for you. However, in your case, some "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" may remain in the Google API console. And they linked SHA1 and package. So a small clean up there could help. Just be sure those "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" are not used somewhere else in your organization.

Comment: Note on Firebase: you may also face some issues when you will link your Games with Firebase. I can detail later if needed. But as Firebase linking is optional, let's start without to fix your first issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the SHA-1 & SHA-256 fingerprints from Firebase and was able to create a new Google Play games service linked to my packagename and SHA1.

Really wish there was one source of truth in Google and I didn't need to jump around between, 
***Google play console***, 
***Firebase console*** and 
***Google API console*** to get things working.

[Remove SHA's from firebase, or delete the instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhFfW.png)